# Difference between Color.Transparent and Color.Unspecified

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What's the difference between `Color.Transparent` and `Color.Unspecified` in Jetpack Compose? Is one of them better for performance than the other? Which of these should be used if I don't want to see any background colour on my compenent at all?

```
OutlinedCard(colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)) {}
```

or

```
OutlinedCard(colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Unspecified)) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both are transparent color. `Color.Unspecified`, or other Unspecified  options that also exist for Size, Offset are to allow comparison using `isSpecified` or `isUnspecified` functions for corresponding instances. With Color as i recall both Color.Transparent and Color.Unspecified return same result for these 2 comparison functions.

Color.Unspecified or other ones are more suitable when you wish to check if user has entered any input while transparent defines a color choice, of course this is not set in stone you can use both.

The distinction is more apparent especially when using Offset.Unspecified or Size.Unspecified when you don't want to draw something on screen initially instead drawing something at some position or with zero size.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Unspecified())

> val Unspecified: Color
>
> Because Color is an inline class, **this represents an unset value
> without having to box the Color**. **It will be treated as Transparent
> when drawn**. A Color can compare with Unspecified for equality or use
> isUnspecified to check for the unset value or isSpecified for any
> color that isn't Unspecified.

So it's like **Transparent** when drawn!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whom you are developing app if it is for a company where stability and consistency are more important than performance than use transparent

```kotlin
OutlinedCard(colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)) {}
```

or if you are targeting older devices use unspecified which also slightly more performant than transparent

```kotlin
OutlinedCard(colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Unspecified)) {}
```

Comment: Why/how would it be more performant?